# Exclude files that start with number - batch script

Tags: sql, batch-file

How to exclude the files from the loop -> if the file name in a directory starts with number.

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd -S %SName% -U %UName% -P %Pwd% -d %DbName% -Q "EXECUTE sp_deploy %%~nG" >> "C:\%%~nG.sql" 2>&1
```

I do not want to execute the sql if the file name start with a number. How can I stop that..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"if '%%~nG' not like '[0-9]%' EXECUTE sp_deploy %%~nG"
```

Comment: Thanks Andomar.. But my file name has some space... so if i give 01-Altertable tcheck.sql this is not reading completely... kindly assist